# Solve Graphically

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Solve the given systems of equations by graphical method:
$$x^2+y^2=5$$ and $$y=2x$$

My Attempt

Let's have a look at the second equation ;
$$y=2x$$
      This is a linear equation in two variables and while solving it Graphically we have;

When $y=2, x=1$
When $y=4, x=2$
When $y=6, x=3$
Plotting these Co ordinates in the graph gives a straight line.

But I don't have any idea regarding the first equation $x^2+y^2=5$. I have never solved any equation like this.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: https://www.printablepaper.net/category/graph

Comment: Does $x^2+y^2=c^2$ look familiar to you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$x^2+y^2=5$ is a circle.
$(x – h)^2 + (y – k)^2 = r^2$ is the general formula for a circle, with the center at the point $(h, k)$ and the radius $r$. 

So in your case, $(h, k)=(0,0)$, the circle is centered at the origin with a raidus of $\sqrt5$.
The graph looks like this:[image]